# How to include user stories from multiple backlogs in one TFS team board?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible in TFS to create three backlogs within the same project and move user stories from each of the backlogs into an iteration?

For example, if the team supports three different applications and therefore has three different backlogs and may do user stories for each of the applications for a given sprint.

If this is not possible in TFS, what is the best way to setup the project/backlog/areas to reflect the team working on user stories for three different applications? Because the other alternative seems to be having three separate projects, backlogs, team board and burndown charts which is not ideal due to the overhead of updating each board.

Comment: Single backlog with 3 Backlog area's for the 3 different apps. Or a single backlog with tags for each application.

Answer (score 3):

If you team supports different applications you may create three TFS teams for each application on one project with the same (or not) set of team members. In this case your team members just select needed TFS team and get backlogs, boards, dashboards for needed application: [Add teams and team members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/multiple-teams), [Switch team project or team focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/teams/switch-team-context), [Work with multi-team ownership of backlog items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/work-multi-team-ownership-backlogs), [Visibility across teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/visibility-across-teams)